# Changing the weight paint of bone changes another

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify

So I'm trying to use rigify to rig a model, and I've run into a very specific problem that I have given up trying to solve. The eye lids have influence over the actual eyes themselves, so I tried to weight paint them away. However, when I select the bone and change the weight to 0 it doesn't remove the weight, it just transfers it to another eye lid bone. Now I thought I was being clever by locking the vertex group of the so the weight paint couldn't change on me, but when I get to the final eye lid bone, I can't change the weight paint, and all the previous weight paint has been absorbed by it. In other words the eye lid bones must have a combined total of at least "1" across the bones. Help[image]

Comment: Have you enabled the *Auto Normalize* option in the tool settings? It's in the *N-panel > Tool* tab, and there the checkbox  *Options > Auto Normalize*

Comment: Auto Normalize has been enabled since the start. I went ahead and unchecked and rechecked it to see if it did anything, and it didn't.